# xml sorting fn not working

Tags: xml, xpath

XML Input as below:

```
  <Global>
    <ProductFood>
        <foodName>Burger</foodName>
        <foodName>Snack</foodName>
    </ProductFood>
    <ProductToy>     
      <Product ProductID="1"> 
         <productName>Doll</productName> 
         <Color>Green</Color> 
      </Product> 
      <Product ProductID="2"> 
         <productName>Ball</productName> 
         <Color>White</Color> 
      </Product>       
    </ProductToy>
 </Global>
```

XSLT Code that i have is below:

```
<xsl:template match="//Products"> 
    <html> 
        <body> 
            <Products> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ProductToy" > 
                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </Products> 
        </body> 
    </html> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Product"> 
    <xsl:element name="product"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="ProductName/text()" /> 
        <xsl:element name="productID"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@ProductID" /> 
        </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

i wanted the output to return product attribute name by ascending.but my sorting is not working as it still shows the product ball first then only the doll.please advise how to make it work.

Comment: You are storing the ProductToy elements but there is only one ProductToy element; sorting a set with only one element is not a very useful operation. Moreover, you are sorting them by the value of the name attribute, but neither your ProductToy element nor anything else has a name attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Global">
    <html>
      <body>
        <Products>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//Product">
            <xsl:sort select="productName"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Products>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product">
    <product name="{productName}">
      <productID>
        <xsl:value-of select="@ProductID"/>
      </productID>
    </product>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <Products>
      <product name="Ball">
        <productID>2</productID>
      </product>
      <product name="Doll">
        <productID>1</productID>
      </product>
    </Products>
  </body>
</html>
```